# Accessing 'this' table cells value

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I have a form, after form has been filled and add button pressed - all the values from the form get to PouchDB and then into the table in the browser. 
I need to make an "edit" option. The idea is:

```
<td ondblclick='updateVaucher()' style='cursor: pointer'>"+data[i].doc.vaucherID+
                "</td>
```

Now the question is: how do I get the value of the cell (which is an ID) so that then I could download the rest of the information into the form?

I would like it to be something like that:

```
function updateVaucher(){
  var mydoc = this.td.value;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Use `ondblclick='updateVaucher(this)'` then get the object in `function updateVaucher(obj)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a reference to the element inside the function, you can pass the element to it from the event handler:

```
ondblclick='updateVaucher(this)'
```

You can get the content of an element via `innerText` or [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) (cross-browser):

```
function updateVaucher(ele){
  var mydoc = ele.textContent || ele.innerText;
  ...
}
```

[Learn more about event handling in the browser](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html).